# How to rewrite directory for multiple level directories

Tags: .htaccess

This is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(views|css|js|media|partials|php)
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1
```

This is my project structure:
[image: project structure]

The idea is that all my HTML files are structured in the folder `views`, but I don't want my URL to be http://example.com/views/index but just http://example.com/index without the views-part.

This is working fine in the following case:
http://example.com/account/

But fails as soon as I try to access a file in the accounts-folder e.g: http://example.com/account/voeg-kind-toe

That results in a 404. Seems like this `.htaccess` solution only works for one-level directories.

Edit:
Interesting: If I place the bottom two lines on top (so placing the code to rewrite the view-part before the code to remove the php-extension); the php-extension works but the /views//part don't.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? (This should "work", providing there are no other conflicts. However, it's not strictly correct the way it's currently written.)

Comment: Where is `voeg-kind-toe.php` located?

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /views/$1  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ views/ [L]
```

Comment: Will this also remove php extensions from all my pages?

Comment: add this at the end of file  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, providing there are no other directives/conflicts then this should still "work" in a *roundabout* way. However, there is an issue with the following directive in the order you have placed it:

> ```
> # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php
> ```

You aren't testing for files in the `/views` subdirectory. But also, `REQUEST_FILENAME` does not necessarily contain what (I think) you think it does. When you request `/account/voeg-kind-toe` (an entirely virtual URL path) then `REQUEST_FILENAME` contains `/account` (it actually contains an absolute filesystem path, but I've kept it brief). So, the above is testing whether `/account.php` exists, not `/account/voeg-kind-toe.php`, or even `/views/account/voeg-kind-toe.php` - which is presumably the intention.

So, on the *first pass*, the above condition fails, no rewrite occurs, and processing continues...

The second rule then rewrites the request for `/account/voeg-kind-toe` to `/views/account/voeg-kind-toe`. Providing there are no further mod_rewrite directives, the rewrite engine then starts over. This time, `/views/account/voeg-kind-toe` is the input.

On the *second pass*, `REQUEST_FILENAME` is `/views/account/voeg-kind-toe` (since `/views/account` is a physical directory) and the request is rewritten to `/views/account/voeg-kind-toe.php` (since the filesystem check should be successful). Providing you have no other directives then processing should now stop.

> This is working fine in the following case: `http://example.com/account/`

`/account/` is simply rewritten to `/views/account/` by the last rule.

> Edit: Interesting: If I place the bottom two lines on top (so placing the code to rewrite the view-part before the code to remove the php-extension); the php-extension works but the /views//part don't.

The same process as above occurs, EXCEPT this all occurs in a single pass and so is less dependent on other directives that might occur later in the file.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the /views//part don't"?

Assuming you only have `.php` files within the `/views` directory and all URLs are intended to target the `/views` subdirectory and you don't need to reference directories directly then you could do this is a single directive and rewrite everything that does not contain (what looks like) a file extension to `/views/<whatever>.php`.

For example:

```
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ /views%{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The `L` (`last`) flag is required if you have other mod_rewrite directives that follow - to prevent additional processing.

This does mean you can't rely on the directory index. ie. You need to request `/index` (as in your example), not simply `/` to serve `/views/index.php`.

(You still need your first rule that removes `.php` from the requested URL - although this is only strictly necessary if you are changing an existing URL structure, where you previously used `.php` on the URLs.)